# Show just one column Datagridview mysql vb.net

Tags: mysql, vb.net, datagridview

I have database table **schedule** and it has 7 columns (ID, Reserve_No, Lastname, Firstname, Service, PhoneNumber, Date_Time) I want to show column **Date_Time** only.

Here's my code for showing database on Datagridview

```
Dim DataAdapter As New MySqlDataAdapter
        Dim DataTable As New DataTable
        Dim cmd As New MySqlCommand
        MySqlConn.Open()
        With cmd
            .Connection = MySqlConn
            .CommandText = "SELECT * FROM schedule"
        End With
        DataAdapter.SelectCommand = cmd
        DataTable.Clear()
        DataAdapter.Fill(DataTable)
        DataGridView1.DataSource = DataTable
        MySqlConn.Close()
```

Comment: SELECT Date_Time FROM schedule

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Selecting columns from MySQL table :

> If you do not want to see entire rows from your table, just name the
>   columns in which you are interested, separated by commas.

Change your query to select one column :

```
    Dim DataAdapter As New MySqlDataAdapter
    Dim DataTable As New DataTable
    Dim cmd As New MySqlCommand
    MySqlConn.Open()
    With cmd
        .Connection = MySqlConn
        .CommandText = "SELECT Date_Time FROM schedule"
    End With
    DataAdapter.SelectCommand = cmd
    DataTable.Clear()
    DataAdapter.Fill(DataTable)
    DataGridView1.DataSource = DataTable
    MySqlConn.Close()
```

> Also you can to minimize the output, retrieve each unique output
>   record just once by adding the keyword DISTINCT.

[More reference](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/selecting-columns.html)